# Como destruir uma sessão específica?

Tags: php, session

É o seguinte: eu tenho uma aplicação/jogo que usa sessões para memorizar os dados que os usuários escolheram.

Sempre que o usuário reiniciar o jogo eu preciso zerar as informações, então estava utilizando perfeitamente o

```
     session_destroy();
```

até que precisei usar

```
$_SESSION['email'] e $_SESSION['senha']
```

para que o usuário só tivesse acesso à página do jogo se estivesse logado.

Então agora se eu uso o

```
session_destroy();
```

as sessões que mantém o usuário logado também são destruídas e ele é redirecionado para a página inicial.

Tentei usar

```
unset();
```

para esvaziar somente as sessões que preciso reiniciar, mas aí o sistema não funciona adequadamente. As vezes tenho que ficar apertando o botão reiniciar várias vezes...

Alguma sugestão?

**Vejam o que estou fazendo:**

```
      if ($_POST['entrada'] === "ex" ) //primeiro if
      {

          if(isset($_SESSION['palavra']))
           {
              unset($_SESSION['palavra']); 
           }

          if(isset($_SESSION['sessoes']))
          {
           unset($_SESSION['sessoes']); 
          }              
         if(isset($_SESSION['letra']))   
         {
          unset($_SESSION['letra']); 
         }


      }//fecha o primeiro if
```

Dentro desse if principal estão mais de dez sessões para unsetar, coloquei só três para exemplificar o que estou fazendo.

**VAR DUMP no $_SESSION:**
array(13) { ["fundo"]=> string(5) "fundo" ["email"]=> string(25) "xxxxx@gmail.com" ["senha"]=> string(8) "deusdeus" ["classe"]=> string(7) "entrada" ["contagem"]=> int(3) ["pos"]=> int(0) ["pos_2"]=> int(2) ["erro"]=> string(1) "v" ["erro_1"]=> string(1) "m" ["erro_2"]=> string(1) "w" ["erro_3"]=> string(1) "x" ["erro_4"]=> string(1) "z" ["erro_5"]=> string(1) "y" }

Comment: O que tem dentro do `$_SESSION` para cada usuário, e o que precisa ser excluído? É sim o caso de usar `unset`, mas só para os dados que você não precisa manter (e não para a sessão inteira do usuário).

Comment: Eu usei o unset em todas as sessões que preciso apagar ao reiniciar o jogo. No entanto nem sempre funciona de forma imediata. As vezes eu tenho que ficar clicando uma, duas, três vezes no botão para reinicializar. Dá a impressão que ao clicar no botão estou apagando aos poucos as sessões. No entanto todas as sessões que preciso apagar estão dentro de um if, logo se a condição for verdadeira (no caso, se o botão reiniciar for clicado) todas aquelas sessões sofrerão unset.

Comment: Não está claro o que você está chamando de "as sessões". Só existe uma sessão por usuário. E dentro dela tem vários dados. Você pode [edit] sua pergunta e incluir a saída de `var_dump($_SESSION)` para um usuário qualquer?

Comment: Eu expliquei que antes de usar sessão para logar o usuário eu já estava usando sessões em meu jogo. Coloquei na pergunta algumas.

Comment: @IWannaKnow seria mais lógico simplesmente zerar as variaveis do jogo apenas em vez de destruir a sessão.

Comment: Você pode dividir as variáveis do jogo, por exemplo, `$_SESSION['jogo']['palavra']` etc. `$_SESSION['jogo']` seria uma array. Aí quando precisar limpar é só limpar essa chave inteira, com tudo que tem dentro.

Comment: @bfvaretto Coloquei o var dump na pergunta, são várias sessões... Bacco E como zero as variáveis do jogo? Mas já digo que muitas variáveis estão armazenadas em sessões justamente porque não posso perder os dados quando o usuário atualizar a página.

Comment: Esclarecendo a terminologia, a sessão é uma só por usuário (mesmo antes de logar, considere a sessão como a janela do browser onde está seu site). Para cada sessão podem ser associadas múltiplas variáveis, que se chamam "variáveis de sessão". O que você está chamando de "as sessões" são "variáveis de sessão".

Comment: @bfvaretto Eu li isso agora a pouco em um fórum. Enfim... Respondendo a seu comentário anterior: se te entendi, não posso fazer isso porque existem sessões que só serão setadas caso outras existam, ou seja existem sessões que nem sempre existirão. Não posso colocar todas em um array.

Comment: Eu acho que pode, é só checar o que existe em `$_SESSION['jogo']`, em vez de checar diretamente em `$_SESSION`.

Comment: Na lógica de meu código existe coisas que só acontecem se uma variável de sessão estiver setada, em outros casos se não estiver. Se eu criar um array com todas variáveis dentro eu estaria setando todas elas ainda que estivessem vazias. Ou não? Sim, mas por que você sugeriu unsetar tudo de uma só vez? Existe algum bug se tentar unsetar várias variáveis de sessão? Acho que você sugeriu o que pensou ser mais prático...

Comment: Tudo indica que você esteja fazendo de uma maneira correta. O que eu sugeri é só um atalho. Se o que você está fazendo só funciona às vezes, fica difícil saber o porquê sem conhecer melhor o seu código. Pela parte que está postada, não dá pra dizer.

Comment: Era você que queria fazer um sistema de game para palavra cruzada? Pode aproveitar e dar um exemplo mais concreto?

Comment: Esse "jogo" na verdade é de adivinhar a palavra. Mas o problema é só nessa parte mesmo, na hora de  dar unset nas sessões. Tanto que tudo está funcionando perfeitamente quando uso o session_destroy();

Comment: O seu codigo permite uma análise completa? Você pode por no codepad para ficara mais fácil identificar o problema?

Comment: Cara, você pediu o código para fazer uma análise e eu me senti na obrigação de encontrar algum erro que poderia estar causando isso e no fim eu estava esquecendo de unsetar uma das variáveis de sessão. São tantas...  Desculpa se fiz alguém perder tempo, mas o código está todo certo, foi um descuido meu apenas. Obrigado, sua resposta traz tudo e pode ser útil para um visitante. @PapaCharlie

Comment: I Wanna Know, disponha

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Atualização

Você pode fazer subgrupos na sessão:

```
$_SESSION['login'] = array( 'email' => 'email@domain.com' , 'senha' => 'userpassword' );
$_SESSION['games'] = array( 'palavra' => 'Helicóptero' , 'letra' => 'a' );
```

Sua sessão será em 2 grupos: dados do login(email, senha), e dados do jogo(palavra, letra...)

```
[login] => Array('email' => 'email@domain.com' , 'senha' => 'userpassword')
[games] => Array('palavra' => 'Helicóptero' , 'letra' => 'a' )
```

Você poderá remover um indice especifico da 'sessão games' usando `unset( $_SESSION['games']['palavra'] )` ou para reiniciar o jogo você remove a sessão completa do jogo usando `unset( $_SESSION['games'] )`, isso manterá a sessão do usuário inalterada.

---

**Removendo indices da session**

Unset destri uma variável da sessão, enquanto session_destroy() vai destruir todas as sessões para o usuário.

```
unset( $_SESSION['palavra'] );  // irá remover apenas os dados de 'palavra'
session_destroy();  // irá remover todas as sessões do usuário.
```

---

Não sei se supre sua dúvida, mas sou dar exemplo simples...

```
// criando sessões de login
session_start();
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$senha = $_SESSION['senha'];

// criando sessões do jogo
$senha = $_SESSION['palavra'];
$senha = $_SESSION['letra'];

// removendo todas as sessões
session_start();
session_destroy();
unset( $_SESSION );

// removendo sessões do jogo
// opção 1)
unset( $_SESSION['palavra'] );
unset( $_SESSION['senha'] );

// opção 2)
$_SESSION['palavra'] = null;
$_SESSION['senha'] = null;
```

Masta você usar como condição em cada session que você precisar verificar.

Comment: É o que estou fazendo. Suponhámos que que $_SESSION['palavra']=casa; Então eu faço unset( $_SESSION['palavra'] ); Mas em seguida eu preciso adiconar uma nova palavra dentro da $_SESSION['palavra']. Da mesma forma preciso adicionar novas letras em cada sessão responsável por armazenar uma letra.

Comment: Eu postei na pergunta como estou unsetando as sessões dentro de um if. Devo fazer um if para cada sessão que eu quiser unsetar?

Comment: Depende da sessão que você quiser apagar. Aparentemente vai ser manualmente para cada indice.

Answer (score 5):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
session_start();
$tmpemail = $_SESSION['email'];
$tmpsenha = $_SESSION['senha'];
session_destroy();
session_start();
$_SESSION['email'] = $tmpemail;
$_SESSION['senha'] = $tmpsenha;
```