# Implementando logoff no meu sistema de login com UNSET SESSION

Tags: php, mysql

possuo o seguinte arquivo de login.php:

```
<?php


require_once('conexao.php');

// FETCH DATA FROM FORM USING METHOD POST
// IF BUTTON NAME "LOGIN" IS SET
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {




// FETCH DATA FROM INPUT FIELD
$user = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['usuario']);
$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['password']);

  // CHECK ALL FIELD HAS BEEN FILLED UP
 if ($user && $pass) {

   // QUERY FROM DATABASE
  $query= mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='".$user."'");
  $checkuser= mysqli_num_rows($query);

   // CHECK IF USERNAME EXIST ON DATABASE
  if($checkuser != 1) {

    // I'LL BE SETTING A VARIABLE IF YOUR DOESN'T EXIST
   header("Location: ../login.php" . "?erro=3");
  }

   // FETCHING PASSWORD IN DATABASE WHERE USERNAME COINCIDES
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
   $checkpass= $row['senha'];


    // CHECK IF ENTERED PASSWORD MEETS THE USERNAME PASSWORD
   if ($pass== $checkpass) {

     // IF ALL OKAY SET SESSION
    setcookie("usuario", $user, time()+7200);
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $user;
    $_SESSION['start'] = time();
    $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (60 * 60 * 60);
    header("Location: ../admin.php");

    exit();
   } else {

     // SET VARIABLE THAT'LL SHOW IF USER PASSWORD IS INCORRECT

    header("Location: ../login.php" . "?erro=1");
   }
  }
 } else {

  // SET VARIABLE IF ALL FIELD ARE NOT FILLED UP

 header("Location: ../login.php" . "?erro=2");
 }
}


?>
```

O mesmo está funcionando OK, vai para o painel, tudo certinho. Porém, dentro do painel eu tenho um botão de "Logoff", que queria que retornasse para a tela de login e fechasse a sessão. Andei lendo que seria com UNSET. No caso o logout.php teria apenas um UNSET $_SESSION['usuario']? Outro porém que notei no meu código é que mudando a URL para admin.php o sistema leva o usuário ao painel sem verificar se está logado ou não.

Comment: Não vou arriscar uma resposta pq tbm to aprendendo sessions... mas dá uma olhada no arquivo admin.php, porque vc precisa ter iniciado a sessão com `session_start()` ou no seu caso com `require_once('conexao.php');`, e colocar um regra pra quando o usuário não estiver logado. Por exemplo: `if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) { faça algo}`. Assim, se não estiver logado vai executar o que está entre as chaves e não vai mostrar o painel...

Comment: Sobre o logout é o que Rafael falou na resposta, mas acho que tbm é bom fazer um `$_SESSION = array();` antes de `session_destroy;` pra apagar as variáveis, e se tiver trabalhando com cookies tem que setar um tempo no passado pra eles, p.ex: `setcookie('user_id', '', time() - 3600);`.

Comment: Pergunta relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31393/como-destruir-uma-sess%C3%A3o-espec%C3%ADfica/31423

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer logout/logoff redirecione o usuario para um arquivo com o nome `logout.php` (por exemplo).

Dentro deste arquivo use:

```
session_start(); // Pega a sessão que já foi iniciada
session_destroy(); // Cancela/Exclui a sessão iniciada
header('location: login.php'); //Redireciona para a pagina de login
```